# Required base class for property

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, base-class

I have a class that has a property, and I want to force that this property is of a Type that inherits from a base type

```
public abstract class BasePropertyClass
{
    public string A { get; set;}
}

public class MyPropClass : BasePropertyClass
{
    public string B { get; set;}
}

public class MyOtherPropClass : BasePropertyClass
{
    public string C { get; set;}
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyPropClass MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public MyOtherPropClass MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}
```

So, how can I make an Interface-ish solution that **MyClass** and **MyOtherClass** must have a property **MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass** that must have **BasePropertyClass** as base type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better explain @Selman22 answer, you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class ConstrainedClass<T>
   where T: BasePropertyClass
   {
     public T MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
   }
```

In this way, if you declare the other to classes like this:

```
public class MyClass:ConstrainedClass<MyPropClass>
{
}

public class MyOtherClass:ConstrainedClass<MyOtherPropClass>
{
}
```

you will obtain the same classes as you declared in your question, plus you have the constraint in the property.

If your classes already inerhits from another class, you need an additional step:

```
 public interface ConstrainedInterface<T> 
 where T: BasePropertyClass
{
  T MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}
```

and after you must explicitly define the two properties:

```
public class MyClass : ConstrainedInterface<MyPropClass>
{
 public MyPropClass MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class MyOtherClass : ConstrainedInterface<MyOtherPropClass>
{
 public MyOtherPropClass MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thx, I didn't know you could use generics in Interfaces. Today I've learned ;-)

Comment: @Niko if you want learn more about generics and interfaces take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can make your class generic and add a constraint

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : BasePropertyClass
{
     public T MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification: the previous MyClass will be `MyClass<MyPropClass>` and the previous MyOtherClass will be `MyClass<MyOtherPropClass>`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use your base type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public BasePropertyClass Property1 { get; set;}
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public BasePropertyClass Property2 { get; set;}
}
```

since both `MyPropClass` and `MyOtherPropClass` inherits the same base type, `BasePropertyClass`.
This way you could assign to either `Property1`  or `Property2` and object of type `MyPropClass` or `MyOtherPropClass`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly, because the implemented property must be exactly of the type specified in the interface.

Alternative to @Selman's generic solution, you can do so using a backing field:

```
public interface MyClassInterface
{
    BasePropertyClass MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass { get; set;}
}

public class MyClass : MyClassInterface
{
    private MyPropClass _actualProperty;
    public BasePropertyClass MyPropThatMustInheritBasePropertyClass 
    { 
        get { return _actualProperty; } 
        set { _actualProperty = (MyPropClass)value; }
    }
}
```

This assumes the not specified requirement *"I want to have a member of the derived type in the implementing class"*, which `MyPropClass _actualProperty` fulfills.

This will not ensure type safety for the setter, which may throw a cast exception when setting a variable of the wrong type (in this case `MyOtherPropClass`).